# Auto select value of drop down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress website and I have integrated a form plugin to it. The form is located on a subdirectory of the domain. On the main website, I have a button and want it to redirect automatically to the form webpage and auto select an option from the drop down.

Example: The button is on www.xyz.com, which when clicked goes to www.xyz.com/form and auto selects option A from the new web page.

Below is the code for the form's dropdown.

```
<div class="md-select-menu-container md-active md-clickable" aria-hidden="false" id="select_container_10" style="display: block; left: 684px; top: 338px; min-width: 538px; font-size: 14px;"><md-select-menu class="_md" style="transform-origin: 253px 32px 0px;"><md-content><md-option class="armSelectOption101 armSelectOptionLTR md-ink-ripple" value="subscriber" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="select_option_7" selected="selected"><div class="md-text">Subscriber</div><div class="md-ripple-container" style=""></div></md-option><md-option class="armSelectOption101 armSelectOptionLTR md-ink-ripple" value="provider" tabindex="0" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_8"><div class="md-text">Provider</div><div class="md-ripple-container" style=""></div></md-option></md-content></md-select-menu></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameter to url after button click on [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) for example:

```
www.xyz.com/form/?option=a
```

And after redirect to form page get it using JS.

Check this source for reference:

https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/